# Different parenthesis sizes in frac, how to solve it

Tags: fractions, mathjax

In the below equation

```
$\Big(R - \left(\frac{D}{Q} \right) \Big) \Big( R - \left(\frac{D}{P} \right)\Big)$.
```

the `\frac{D}{Q}` and `\frac{D}{P}` have different sized parenthesis. However, if we use

```
$$\Big(R - \left(\frac{D}{Q} \right) \Big) \Big( R - \left(\frac{D}{P} \right)\Big)$$
```

they will have the same size.

What is the reason here and how we can solve the issue?

I'm using MathJax and tested the issue in LaTeX, too. When I put `\displaystyle` into the equation (with one dollar) it resolved but everything becomes bigger as double dollar.

Comment: `$` places math in so-called `\textstyle` (for inline math), wheres `$$` places math in `\displaystyle`, setting the equation apart from the text, and using larger notations in some cases.  In LaTeX, `$$` should be avoided.  Use `\[...\]` instead or an `equation` environment, or one of the `amsmath` environments.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've updated the question, I was tough this is only LaTeX related.

Comment: Anyawy, it's usually better to specify sizes with `\Bigl ... `\Bigr` and the like. This being said, the reason is certainly that the letter `Q` has a descender, which is taken into account to determine the parentheses size in the | \left ... `right` version.

Comment: It may not be relevant here, but it's worth noting that the "sized" parentheses in different fonts aren't uniformly graded, so substituting font B for font A may get different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is due to the fact that `Q` has a descendant while `P` doesn't, so in trying to make things tighter `\left` and `\right` are able to choose a smaller size.

You can solve it with

```latex
$\Big(R - \left(\frac{D}{Q} \right) \Big) \Big( R - \left(\frac{D}{\mathstrut P} \right)\Big)$.
```

or a `\phantom{Q}` --- at leat in LaTeX. Or, better, use `\bigr` etc as you are doing in the external brackets.

MathJax I don't know, and it's not on topic here --- the engine is very different.

Comment: This solved in MathJax, too.